# How to configure sendmail and avoid localhost.localdomain?

Tags: sendmail

I have been added to the CBL list because our servers with fedora 17 (we have been updated them) now are sending mails identifying themselves as localhost.localdomain.

I have run this command from one server with fedora 17

echo “This will go into the body of the mail.” | sendmail -s "Hello world" abraham.sustaita@gmail.com

And this is that is in the mail:

```
Received: from app03.site.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by app03.site.com (8.14.5/8.14.5) with ESMTP id q6UHk0xp018117;
    Mon, 30 Jul 2012 17:46:00 GMT
```

But from other server with fedora 12, the same command send the mail with this:

```
Received: by app05.site.com (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id 2DFFF24E67E; Mon, 30 Jul 2012 17:46:38 +0000 (UTC)
```

How can I configure sendmail so it doesn't send localhost.localdomain? I have follow this guide: http://www.redhat.com/magazine/025nov06/features/email/index.html but it didn't worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have being able to fix this.

The only thing I had to do was add

```
dnl define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `app05.site.com')dnl
```

To

```
/etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

And then

```
make -C /etc/mail/
```

Comment: I believe you need to omit the `dnl` before the `define` to make it work.

Comment: At least at that time it worked... don't know if things are quite different now...